# How to reset database using php

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I tried to write the function which can reset the tables in postgresql database, but it always reminds me that

> Error: timeout of 5000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
>       at mocha.js:4455:19

My codes are as follows. How can I solve this problem?

```
function reset_database($dbh) {
    $query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'users', 'posts', 'voting', 'hashtag';";
    $result = pg_query($dbh, $query);
    if (!result) {
        return array( 'status' => 0 );
    }
    else {
        return array( 'status' => 1 );

    $query  = "CREATE TABLE users(username VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);";
    $result = pg_query($dbh, $query);

    if (!result) {
        return array( 'status' => 0 );
    }
    else {
        return array( 'status' => 1 );

    $query = "CREATE TABLE posts(pID serial, username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, content VARCHAR(42),time timestamp,coorX INTEGER,coorY INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(pID),FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES users(username) ON DELETE CASCADE);";
    $result = pg_query($dbh, $query);

    if (!result) {
        return array( 'status' => 0 );
    }
    else {
        return array( 'status' => 1 );

    $query = "CREATE TABLE voting(username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,pID INTEGER NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(username, pID),FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users(username) ON DELETE CASCADE,FOREIGN KEY (pID) REFERENCES posts ON DELETE CASCADE);";
    $result = pg_query($dbh, $query);
    if (!result) {
        return array( 'status' => 0 );
    }
    else {
        return array( 'status' => 1 );

    $query = "CREATE TABLE hashtag(tag VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,pID INTEGER NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(tag),FOREIGN KEY(pID) REFERENCES posts(pID) ON DELETE CASCADE);";
    $result = pg_query($dbh, $query);

    if (!result) {
        return array( 'status' => 0 );
    }
    else {
        return array( 'status' => 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run the code again, it said "Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (readyState, getResponseHeader, ...) } to be undefined (http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shanshaz/cmuyak/tests/chai.js:870)
Error: Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (readyState, getResponseHeader, ...) } to be undefined (chai.js:870)
    at global.onerror (mocha.js:6447:10)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `TRUNCATE` command:

```
$query = "TRUNCATE ONLY users, posts, voting, hashtag RESTART IDENTITY";
$result = pg_query($dbh, $query);
if (!result) {
  return array( 'status' => 0 );
} else {
  return array( 'status' => 1 );
}
```

ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html